# React Native + Kurento WebRTC Media Server

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, kurento

I just want to know that is there any specific way that we can integrate [Kurento WebRTC Media Server](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.13.0/) within a react-native application. If we can integrate this, I just want to know how exactly are we going to do this.

If you have any certain Ideas/Knowledge regarding this. Please let me know as soon as possible.

Hoping for the best response from the community!

Thanks,
Kalpit

Comment: Did you got the answer ?.
Any reference to do this? I am stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.